# Grails external Jms broker (active mq)

Tags: grails, groovy, jms, activemq-classic

I have what will become an 'external' activemq server I'd like grails to be able to talk to. Right now I am just running it on my dev box.
Here is what I have setup right now:

1) Run activemq server
2) Run activemq/examples using ant to produce messages
3) View ActiveMQ admin site: http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp verify that messages are in the queue.

4) Follow **Mini Tutorial** to create the Service and Controller: http://www.grails.org/ActiveMQ+Plugin

5) Configured my Grails resources.groovy file as follows:

```
beans = {
    jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory){
        targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf -> brokerURL = 'tcp://localhost:61616' }
    }
}
```

When I run the grails app I get a BindException saying port 61616 is already in use.
How do I configure this to use my server that is already running?

I've tried changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and to my LAN ip, but no luck, it keeps trying to setup its own embedded activemq server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activemq plugin is meant for embedding ActiveMQ in your application. It will automatically start it's own server when your app starts.

If you're going to use an external ActiveMQ server then you only need the JMS plugin.

cheers

Lee

Comment: I would start from scratch, only installing the JMS plugin and following its doco. You will find it works perfectly.